# Sprite Kit more than 1 time collision

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, sprite, collision

my game is not this but like this:

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {
    var sprite = SKSpriteNode()

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView)
    {
        self.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFromRect: self.frame)
        self.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = 1
        self.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = 1
        self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(0, -10)
        self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self



    }
    func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
        print("contact")
    }

    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?)
    {
        let spriteTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "Spaceship")
        sprite = SKSpriteNode(texture: spriteTexture)
        sprite.position = CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(self.frame) , y: CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
        sprite.size = CGSizeMake(80, 80)
        sprite.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: spriteTexture, size: CGSizeMake(80, 80))
        sprite.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = 1
        sprite.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 1
        sprite.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = 1
        sprite.physicsBody?.linearDamping = 0;

        self.addChild(sprite)

    }
}
```

if you paste this code and run you see a lot of "contact" string. I want only 1 contact this: 
[image]
so i want when contact only 1 time collision

I edited my question can anyone help?

Comment: then you need to seperate the objects... what do you want? a contact is a contact - you cannot just say you only want contact, that is not how things work.

Comment: Give some more info, like how contact is happening and what kind of physics bodies you have. Also use square physics body as this kind of contact happens with physics body made using polygonFromPath

Comment: I edited, sorry my bad English

Comment: thank you for all answers, I can fix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.Create ‘Base Game’ from Xcode template based on SpriteKit
2.Paste code below to `GameScene` class

```
class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {
    var sprite = SKSpriteNode()

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView)
    {
        self.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFromRect: self.frame)
        self.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = 1
        self.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 1

        self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(0, -10)
        self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self

        self.physicsBody?.restitution = 0.0

    }

    func didEndContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
        print("End contact")
    }

    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?)
    {
        let spriteTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "Spaceship")
        sprite = SKSpriteNode(texture: spriteTexture)
        sprite.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: spriteTexture, size: CGSizeMake(80, 80))

        sprite.size = CGSizeMake(80, 80)

        sprite.position = CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(self.frame) , y: CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
        sprite.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = 1
        sprite.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 1
        sprite.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = 1
        sprite.physicsBody?.fieldBitMask = 1
        sprite.physicsBody?.restitution = 0

        self.addChild(sprite)

    }
}
```

**IMPORTANT NOTE** Try to use `didEndContact` delegate method instead of `didBeginContact`. In this case you'll get only one invoke while `didBeginContact` invokes several times.

Comment: thank you for answer, in my game; 2 node collide. I want, when collide only 1 contact, sorry my bad English

Comment: Can you upload your code on github and explain what you need?

Comment: can you see my answer